# ArrayList vs Vector : Which one to use?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, difference

At the very beginning, I'll admit it that I'm an *idiot*; but there's one thing that I just can't seem to understand. I can't seem to find much difference between `ArrayList` and `Vector` other than this:

> "...*(This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except that it is unsynchronized.)*... "

in the javaDocs of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

So, is this difference *really* an important factor in the way we apply these **two similar classes** when we consider the general scenario (i.e. ruling out the application in *Thread-based programming*)? Are there any other *marked* differences? If so, please tell me. If not, then which one is the *most preferred* or *generally accepted* approach?

Comment: Hope [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-vs) article will give you a better idea.

Comment: ArrayList. Use ArrayList.

Comment: Vector is sort of semi-deprecated.  It's slower, older, so it only sort of fits into the List paradigm, and the synchronization it provides is often not enough to be useful in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @HotLicks. So, I guess that `Vector` is slower because it gobbles up more memory?

Comment: The synchronization isn't free.  Don't know about anything else -- have never looked closely at the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than differences with synchronization, there is also a difference internally when you insert new elements. For both classes, the array within must be increased in size to prevent it from running out of room. Vectors double their size by default. ArrayLists increase their size by half their present size.

Edit:

Also, a couple answers mentioned that Vectors are thread safe. That's true to some extent, but  the whole reason they're *sort-of-deprecated* (I think) is because they're not very useful for most synchronization needs, which is because it synchronizes on every operation (not safe). What you want to do usually is synchronize on a sequence of operations. Vectors don't do that (neither do ArrayLists though) so it's not really the way to go even in situations that require synchronization (basically it's out of your control).

Comment: Thanks! So, I guess that `ArrayList`s grow slower than `Vectors`; and the latter is _semi-deprecated_. So `ArrayList` wins! And are there any other differences?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html):

> "it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector"

Still you can  get a synchronized version of a List with [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29):

```
Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)
```

for example

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

This returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I need help on the _general_ scenario. _Thread_ is not required.

Comment: Here is an extensive article http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/difference-vector-vs-arraylist-in-java.html on the differencies.

Comment: It says "If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector." not it is recommanded to use ArrayList everytime

Comment: Agreed, that's why you get a thread-safe version with Collections.synchronizedList.

Answer (score 3):

The major difference between the two is that the vectors are synchronized, so they are thread-safe, and the ArrayLists are not. Both of them uses an array to store the data they contain, and so whenever you add something to it's content they **will** need to resize themselve, although they do that pretty efficiently, it is to be considered.

ArrayLists also have the advantage to be part of the *Collection* framework so you can use the Collection methods with it to sort, search, etc.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the synchronization, if you are using the List in a threaded program you should use vector, but if not, ArrayList (or other not synchronized implementation of List).

The theoretical reason is that synchronization causes a worse performance of Vector than ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Vector has been around since java 1.0

ArrayList was released with java 1.2

The preferred way is to use ArrayList.

If you are concerned about thread safe, you can synchronize it like this:

List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));